# jQuery Ajax Calls Not Sending Request

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I'm using jQuery.post to send form data to the server. This is failing in Firefox, but not in Chrome or IE (9-11).

```
var validateAndContinue = function(nextPage) {
  // Get form data
  var formData = $('#registrationForm').serialize();
  // Submit form
  $.post(validateURL, formData, function(response) {
    // Irrelevant app code
    ...
  });
};
```

I'm calling this from a function bound to a button using KnockoutJS, but I don't think this is causing the problem. When I open firebug, go to the console, and try to run

```
$.ajax();
```

I get the same exact object as the real call.

> readyState 0
>
> status 0
>
> statusText "SyntaxError: An invalid or illegal string was specified"
>
> abort function(a)
>
> always function()
>
> complete function()
>
> done function()
>
> error function()
>
> fail function()
>
> getAllResponseHeaders function()
>
> getResponseHeader function(a)
>
> overrideMimeType function(a)
>
> pipe function()
>
> progress function()
>
> promise function(a)
>
> setRequestHeader function(a, b)
>
> state function()
>
> statusCode function(a)
>
> success function()
>
> then function()

I also tried adding 'json' as the return type, but no luck there either. There are no errors in the console, and the network tab does not show a request was sent.

The statusText parameter for both the real and dummy calls is

> "SyntaxError: An invalid or illegal string was specified"

It doesn't appear to be my application logic since it's also failing on the dummy call.

I'm using jquery-1.11.0.js.

Comment: What does the `validateURL` contain?

Comment: Also, How does the data you return look like? Is there any xhtml thing there?

Comment: The validateUrl is a simple url 'registration/registerCandidate'. The data is json. something to this affect:

{
    'status': 'success',
    'errors': {
        ....
    }
}.